# How can I do search category.name by using elasticsearch in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

My search working fine.
But I have to type "1" or "2" to get results of "roommate" or "sublet".
Model has a column called `category_id` which is an integer.
Model `Category` has column `:name` which is a string.

Thus, I have category_id 1 is having "roommate" and 2 is "sublet"

below is my Housing model:

```
class Housing < ActiveRecord::Base
    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
    include Elasticsearch::Model
    include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :category

    validates :title, :presence => true
    validates :category_id, :presence => true
    validates :created_at, :presence => false
    validates :user_email, :presence => true
    validates :description, :presence => false
    validates_length_of :title, :maximum => 30

    def self.search(query)
      __elasticsearch__.search(
        {
          query: {
            # multi_match: {
            simple_query_string: {
              query: query,
              fields: ['title^10', 'category_id']
            }
          }
        }
      )
    end

end
```

How can I fix `fields: ['title^10', 'category_id']` So user can search "roommate" instead of must search integer "1" to get result of roommate ?

I tried `fields: ['title^10', 'category.name']` but not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fields: ['title^10', 'category.name']` won't work unless you have correct mapping defined. Elasticsearch doesn't know about your associations. ES is a document store and searches for records using it's own document store. So unless you add your category name to the document stored in ES, you won't be able to search it.

`TL;DR`

Define a mapping. Example:

```
mapping dynamic: 'strict' do
    indexes :category do
      indexes :name
    end
    indexes :title
end
```

Here category will now be stored as nested object inside your index and hence is searchable using `category.name`

Comment: `Category has_many :housings` and `Housing belongs_to :category` is what I have relationship. Should I change it?

Comment: Where are you defining this mapping? If you are defining it in housing model which has `belongs_to :category` association, then it should work just fine. But you need to index all the attributes that you need to search on. Here I have only indexed `category.name` and `title`. And remember that you'll have to rebuild your indexes first as Elasticsearch has already indexed your documents in different format.